# Creating output variables and copying attributes in python xarray netcdf4

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I can create variables and copy over attributes in netcdf4 like this:

```
out_var = hndl_out_nc.createVariable(name_var, var.datatype, var.dimensions)
out_var.setncatts({k: var.getncattr(k) for k in var.ncattrs()})
```

What is the corresponding version for xarray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `var` is an `xarray.DataArray`, you can put it (along with attributes) into a new `xarray.Dataset` simply by writing `ds[name_] = var`. Or you can construct a new DataArray piece by piece with `xarray.DataArray(var.data, var.coords, var.dims, var.attrs)`.